# Is the push replication mode in harbor synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: harbor

Suppose I have 2 harbor repositories, 1 A and 1 B. A has set up replication rules in replication management to replicate mirrors to B via push mode.

So I want to ask when I push the mirror like A, when the push is done, does it also mean that A syncs successfully like B?

Comment: I checked its source code myself and it looks like asynchronous copying, it uses go func for the entry method of copying